# on spark, some operations are being executed before an action is defined?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have the following spark simple example:

```
#1 val lines: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("/data/non_existing_file.txt")
#2 val words: RDD[String] = lines.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
#3 val pairs: RDD[(String, Int)] = words.map(word => (word, 1))
#4 val counts: RDD[(String, Int)] = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
#5 counts.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/result")
```

When I run the program, I get an exception `Input path does not exist: file:/data/non_existing_file.txt"`, as expected.

What is ackward is that I get this exception on line #4. I understand that I don't get this error in line #1, #2 nor #3, because the computation is not executed yet.
The computation is executed only at line #5, when I have the action to write the result to a file. So, why I get an exception on line #4, instead of line #5?

Answer (score 1):

This happens under two conditions:

- `spark.default.parallelism` is not set.
- You provide neither `Partitioner` nor the number of partitions for `reduceByKey`

In this case `reduceByKey` eagerly creates new `HashPartitioner` with the number of partitions equal to the number of partitions of the parent `RDD`. To obtain number of partition, it has to compute input splits. This requires presence of file in input filepath which seems to be missing, hence the error.

Actual `reduceByKey` operation will be performed only after an action call.

This is very similar problem to [Why does sortBy transformation trigger a Spark job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41403670/6910411)