# How to check the number of partitions of a Spark DataFrame without incurring the cost of .rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partition

There are a number of questions about how to obtain the number of partitions  of a n `RDD` and or a `DataFrame` : the answers invariably are:

```
 rdd.getNumPartitions
```

or

```
 df.rdd.getNumPartitions
```

Unfortunately that is an *expensive* operation on a `DataFrame` because the

```
 df.rdd
```

requires conversion from the `DataFrame` to an `rdd`.  This is on the order of the time it takes to run

```
 df.count
```

I am writing logic that *optionally* `repartition`'s or `coalesce`'s a `DataFrame` - based on whether the *current* number of partitions were within a range of acceptable values or instead below or above them.

```
  def repartition(inDf: DataFrame, minPartitions: Option[Int],
       maxPartitions: Option[Int]): DataFrame = {
    val inputPartitions= inDf.rdd.getNumPartitions  // EXPENSIVE!
    val outDf = minPartitions.flatMap{ minp =>
      if (inputPartitions < minp) {
        info(s"Repartition the input from $inputPartitions to $minp partitions..")
        Option(inDf.repartition(minp))
      } else {
        None
      }
    }.getOrElse( maxPartitions.map{ maxp =>
      if (inputPartitions > maxp) {
        info(s"Coalesce the input from $inputPartitions to $maxp partitions..")
        inDf.coalesce(maxp)
      } else inDf
    }.getOrElse(inDf))
    outDf
  }
```

But we can not afford to incur the cost of the `rdd.getNumPartitions` for *every* `DataFrame` in this manner.

Is there not any way to obtain this information - e.g. from querying the online/temporary `catalog` for the `registered` table maybe?

**Update**  The Spark GUI showed the DataFrame.rdd operation as taking as long as the longest sql in the job. I will re-run the job and attach the screenshot in a bit here.

The following is just a *testcase* : it is using a small fraction of the data size of that in production.  The longest `sql` is only five minutes - and this one is on its way to spending that amount of time *as well* (note that the `sql` is *not* helped out here: it also has to execute subsequently thus effectively doubling the cumulative execution time).

[image]

We can see that the `.rdd` operation at `DataFrameUtils` line 30 (shown in the snippet above) takes 5.1mins - and yet the `save` operation *still* took 5.2 mins later -i.e. we did *not* save any time by doing the `.rdd` in terms of the execution time of the subsequent `save`.

Comment: There is a similar question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269477/why-does-the-spark-dataframe-conversion-to-rdd-require-a-full-re-mapping

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no inherent cost of `rdd` component in `rdd.getNumPartitions`, because returned `RDD` is never evaluated.

While you can easily determine this empirically, using debugger (I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader), or establishing that no jobs are triggered in the base case scenario

```
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

```scala
scala> val ds = spark.read.text("README.md")
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> ds.rdd.getNumPartitions
res0: Int = 1

scala> spark.sparkContext.statusTracker.getJobIdsForGroup(null).isEmpty // Check if there are any known jobs
res1: Boolean = true
```

it might be not enough to convince you. So let's approach this in a more systematic way:

- `rdd` returns a `MapPartitionRDD` (`ds` as defined above):

  ```
  scala> ds.rdd.getClass
  res2: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
  ```
- `RDD.getNumPartitions` [invokes `RDD.partitions`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/075447b3965489ffba4e6afb2b120880bc307505/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L267).
- In non-checkpointed scenario [`RDD.partitions` invokes `getPartitions`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/075447b3965489ffba4e6afb2b120880bc307505/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L253) (feel free to trace the checkpoint path as well).
- `RDD.getPartitions` [is abstract](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/075447b3965489ffba4e6afb2b120880bc307505/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L126).
- So the actual implementation used in this case is `MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions`, which simply [delegates the call to the parent](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/71bd7965177cc4d3f1f65fa28fdc8cdd797ad738/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/MapPartitionsRDD.scala#L49).
- There are only `MapPartitionsRDD` between `rdd` and the source.

  ```
  scala> ds.rdd.toDebugString
  res3: String =
  (1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at rdd at <console>:26 []
   |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at rdd at <console>:26 []
   |  MapPartitionsRDD[1] at rdd at <console>:26 []
   |  FileScanRDD[0] at rdd at <console>:26 []
  ```

  Similarly if `Dataset` contained an exchange we would follow the parents to the nearest shuffle:

  ```
  scala> ds.orderBy("value").rdd.toDebugString
  res4: String =
  (67) MapPartitionsRDD[13] at rdd at <console>:26 []
   |   MapPartitionsRDD[12] at rdd at <console>:26 []
   |   MapPartitionsRDD[11] at rdd at <console>:26 []
   |   ShuffledRowRDD[10] at rdd at <console>:26 []
   +-(1) MapPartitionsRDD[9] at rdd at <console>:26 []
      |  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at rdd at <console>:26 []
      |  FileScanRDD[4] at rdd at <console>:26 []
  ```

  Note that this case is particularly interesting, because we actually triggered a job:

  ```
  scala> spark.sparkContext.statusTracker.getJobIdsForGroup(null).isEmpty
  res5: Boolean = false

  scala> spark.sparkContext.statusTracker.getJobIdsForGroup(null)
  res6: Array[Int] = Array(0)
  ```

  That's because we've encountered as scenario where the  partitions cannot be determined statically (see [Number of dataframe partitions after sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53786188/10938362) and [Why does sortBy transformation trigger a Spark job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41403670/10465355)).

  In such scenario `getNumPartitions` will also trigger a job:

  ```
  scala> ds.orderBy("value").rdd.getNumPartitions
  res7: Int = 67

  scala> spark.sparkContext.statusTracker.getJobIdsForGroup(null)  // Note new job id
  res8: Array[Int] = Array(1, 0)
  ```

  however it doesn't mean that the observed cost is somehow related to `.rdd` call. Instead it is an intrinsic cost of finding `partitions` in case, where there is no static formula (some Hadoop input formats for example, where full scan of the data is required).

Please note that the points made here shouldn't be extrapolated to other applications of `Dataset.rdd`. For example `ds.rdd.count` would be indeed expensive and wasteful.

Comment: My job is running in just over half the time after removing the `.rdd.getNumPartitions calls` – javadba

Comment: @javadba I believe we discussed this before - this doesn't invalidate this answer in any way - I explicitly stated that computing partitions can be expensive, and under which general conditions, and that the mistake is to attribute potential cost to conversion to external types. Also, I offered to address any formal counterexample (sorry, hand waving  or anecdotal evidence doesn't count) you provide, or revise (or even revoke) my answer completely, if such hypothetical counterexample proves it is somehow incorrect or incomplete. I really have nothing else to offer here.

Comment: Ah ok the second part of the answer maybe would be helpful to move to(wards) the top: since the first portion comes off as not recognizing the validity of my observations.  I'll award this.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience `df.rdd.getNumPartitions` is very fast, I never encountered taking this more than a second or so.

Alternatively, you could also try

```
val numPartitions: Long = df
      .select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id()).distinct().count()
```

which would avoid using `.rdd`

Comment: I'll try this: in any case will upvote as an interesting approach

Comment: Does that command enhance the performance in comparison to  df.rdd.getNumPartitions?

Comment: @CarlosAG I don't think so