# Why does the Spark DataFrame conversion to RDD require a full re-mapping?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

From the Spark source code:

```
/**
   * Represents the content of the Dataset as an `RDD` of `T`.
   *
   * @group basic
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  lazy val rdd: RDD[T] = {
    val objectType = exprEnc.deserializer.dataType
    rddQueryExecution.toRdd.mapPartitions { rows =>
      rows.map(_.get(0, objectType).asInstanceOf[T])
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2972

The `mapPartitions` can take as long as the time to compute the `RDD` in the first place..   So this makes operations such as

```
df.rdd.getNumPartitions
```

very expensive.  Given that a  `DataFrame` is `DataSet[Row]` and a `DataSet` is composed of `RDD`'s why is a re-mapping required? Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

**TL;DR** That's because the internal `RDD` is not `RDD[Row]`.

> Given that a DataFrame is `DataSet[Row]` and a `DataSet` is composed of RDD's

That's a huge oversimplification. First of all `DataSet[T]`  doesn't mean that you interact with container of `T`. It means that if you use collection-like API (often referred as strongly typed), *internal representation* will be *decoded* into `T`.

The *internal representation* is a binary format used internally by Tungsten.This representation is internal and subject of changes and far too low level to be used in practice.

An intermediate representation, which exposes this data is the `InternalRow` - `rddQueryExecution.toRDD` is in fact `RDD[InternalRow]`. This representation (there are different implementation) still exposes the internal types, is consider "weakly" private, as all objects in `o.a.s.sql.catalyst` (the access is not explicitly restricted, but API is not documented), and rather tricky to interact with.

This where decoding comes into play and why you need full "re-mapping" - to convert internal, often unsafe, objects into external types intended for public usage.

Finally, [to reiterate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54270537/10938362) my previous statement - the code in question won't be executed when `getNumPartitions` is called.

Comment: The above is interesting analysis of the unsafe internal representation so I upvoted for _that_.. You'll need  to remove the statement about "it won't be executed" to get awarded because I have repeatedly run our workflows with and without the count and the latter more or less doubles the time.

Comment: @javadba I suppose the answer referred to the lambda function, which does not execute on `getNumPartitions`