# Spark SQL lazy count

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to use a dataframe count as divisor for calculating percentages.

This is what I'm doing:

```
scala> val df = Seq(1,1,1,2,2,3).toDF("value")
scala> val overallCount = df.count
scala> df.groupBy("value")
         .agg( count(lit(1)) / overallCount )
```

But I would like to avoid the action `df.count` as it will be evaluated immediately.

Accumulators won't help as they will be evaluated in advance.

Is there a way to perform a lazy count over a dataframe?

Comment: What do you want to gain by not performing the action immediately?

Comment: @Shaido, I'm constructing several dataframes and I want them to be evaluated (and cached) only when used.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Dataset.count` you can use simple query

```
val overallCount = df.select(count($"*") as "overallCount")
```

and later `crossJoin`

```
df
  .groupBy("value")
  .agg(count(lit(1)) as "groupCount")
  .crossJoin(overallCount)
  .select($"value", $"groupCount" / $"overallCount")
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. But it seems `crossJoin` is triggering an evaluation.

Comment: @PedroH Definitely not alone (tested using [the same methods I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54270537/10938362). But again under certain conditions Spark might have to determine the number of partitions though I cannot think of any specific case where that might be required here. However if that's the case you can always mark corresponding `vals` as `lazy`).

Comment: Even with `lazy vals`, Spark is evaluating the `vals` when used:
```
lazy val overallCountDF = df.select(count($"*") as "overallCount")
...
.crossJoin(overallCountDF) // <-- evaluated
```