# Why is `spark.range(100).orderBy('id', ascending=False).rdd` not lazy and trigger an action?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

Spark v2.4  pyspark

```
spark.range(100).orderBy('id', ascending=False).rdd
```

When I type the above, it immediately spawn a spark job. I find it suprising as I didn't even specify an action.

E.g. `spark.range(100).repartition(10, 'id').sortWithinPartitions('id').rdd` works as expected in a way that no job is triggered..

A related question is [Why does sortBy transformation trigger a Spark job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403670/why-does-sortby-transformation-trigger-a-spark-job)

It confirms RDD `sortBy` can trigger an action.

But here I am using a DataFrame. `spark.range(100).orderBy('id', ascending=False)` works alright. The job only gets triggered once I access `.rdd`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403670/why-does-sortby-transformation-trigger-a-spark-job

Comment: Thank you this is related. But here I am using a DataFrame. `spark.range(100).orderBy('id', ascending=False)` works alright. The job only gets triggered once I access `.rdd`

Answer (score 1):

Not all transformation is 100% lazy. OrderBy needs to evaluate the RDD to determine the range of data, so it involves both a transformation and an action.